# How to compare two row in same table and provide the mismatch data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two transaction in the same table , i want to compare the two transaction and if there is any mismatch it will provide the mismatch data.

```
        |Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
Trans-1 |ABC |123 |321 |111 |
---------------------------------------------------
Trans-2 |ABC |333 |321 |123|
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
        |col2|col4|
Trans-1 |123 |111 |
---------------------------------------------------
Trans-2 |333 |123 |
```

#

Now i am able to fetch the column value and the different, using the below command. But the result is displaying as one line as below, is there any way to break the line after each transaction?

Actual:-

```
Col1| MAX(Col1) |MIN(Col1) |Col2 |MAX(Col2)| MIN(Col2)|
---------------------------------------------------------
same|ABC        |ABC       |diff |123      |321        |
```

Expected:

```
Col1| MAX(Col1) |MIN(Col1) |
---------------------------
same|ABC        |ABC       |

|Col2 |MAX(Col2)| MIN(Col2)|
----------------------------
|diff |123      |321       |
```

***Team we did a blunder here? guess if we have a single row, in that case all will be same, how to achieve if there is a single transaction then it should FAIL instead of compare the same transaction.***

Comment: A SQL table returns a fixed set of columns.  Your logic suggests that you want a variable number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could try aggregating by `Col1` and then displaying all records sharing a `col1` value whose other columns are not in agreement:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) > 1 THEN 'Col2' END AS Col2_diff,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col3) > 1 THEN 'Col3' END AS Col3_diff,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col4) > 1 THEN 'Col4' END AS Col4_diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) > 1 OR
    COUNT(DISTINCT Col3) > 1 OR
    COUNT(DISTINCT Col4) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to identify the mismatch column, using the above query won't solve my question.

Comment: I updated my answer, which now prints the offending columns in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the columns as the same or different:

```
select (case when max(col1) = min(col1) and count(col1) = count(*) or
                  max(col1) is null then 'same' else 'diff'
        end) as col1,
       (case when max(col2) = min(col2) and count(col2) = count(*) or
                  max(col2) is null then 'same' else 'diff'
        end) as col2,
       (case when max(col3) = min(col3) and count(col3) = count(*) or
                  max(col3) is null then 'same' else 'diff'
        end) as col3,
       (case when max(col4) = min(col4) and count(col3) = count(*) or
                  max(col4) is null then 'same' else 'diff'
        end) as col4
from t;
```

Note that this returns the same columns that are in the data.  A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, unless you use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate` in PL/SQL).

Comment: thanks for the response, its works for me. Is there any work around, now i have 4 column i can manage with this code, guess i have 100 + column how to manage? Also instead of true and  false if it provide the correspondence value and true and false that will be grt.

Comment: @Routray . . . You can use a query or spreadsheet to generate the query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any help on how to run as a query? Also when i run the query mentioned by you, where there is NULL value in both transaction, result shows as DIFF. Is there any way to handle the NULL? if both contents NULL result should be SAME.

Comment: @Routray . . . I added the logic to handle `NULL`s.

Comment: thanks for the update, i have tried with the option you have provided, but still facing the same issue, where there is NULL value its coming as diff.

Comment: @Routray . . . You have the logic `or max(col<n>) is null`?

Comment: Extremely sorry Gordon, its works fine...my bad..Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the details. Now i am able to fletch the column value and the different, using the below command. But the result is displaying as one line as below, is there any way to break the line after each transaction?

Actual:-
Col1| MAX(Col1) |MIN(Col1) |Col2 |MAX(Col2)| MIN(Col2)|
---------------------------------------------------------
same|ABC        |ABC       |diff |123      |321        |
Expected:
Col1| MAX(Col1) |MIN(Col1) |
---------------------------
same|ABC        |ABC  |


|Col2 |MAX(Col2)| MIN(Col2)|
----------------------------
|diff |123      |321       |

Comment: Used your query, is there any way we can break each line after each transaction.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Routray . . . I think you need to ask another question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i have raised another questing with all data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076011/how-to-print-the-result-in-different-line-using-sql-query/57076061#57076061

Comment: HI Gordon, I think we did a blunder here? guess if we have a single row, in that case all will be same, how to achieve if there is a single transaction then it should FAIL instead of compare the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

One possible trick to compare values and considering `null` as regular value (i.e. `null` = `null` is TRUE) is to use `DECODE`

`DECODE(value1,value2,1,0)` returns 1 if the values are equal and 0 if they differ.

Here an example returning the names of the columns with a difference

```
select 
case when decode(max(col1),min(col1),1,0) = 0 then 'col1 ' end ||
case when decode(max(col2),min(col2),1,0) = 0 then 'col2 ' end ||
case when decode(max(col3),min(col3),1,0) = 0 then 'col3 ' end ||
case when decode(max(col4),min(col4),1,0) = 0 then 'col4 ' end as diff_col_names
from trans
```

For wide tables you may pre-generate part of the query direct from the data dictionary

Here an example:

```
select 
replace(q'[case when decode(max(${column_name}),min(${column_name}),1,0) = 0 then '${column_name} ' end ||]',
  '${column_name}',
   column_name) as dif_col_names
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TRANS'
order by column_id;

DIF_COL_NAMES
------------------------------------------------------------------
case when decode(max(COL1),min(COL1),1,0) = 0 then 'COL1 ' end ||
case when decode(max(COL2),min(COL2),1,0) = 0 then 'COL2 ' end ||
case when decode(max(COL3),min(COL3),1,0) = 0 then 'COL3 ' end ||
case when decode(max(COL4),min(COL4),1,0) = 0 then 'COL4 ' end ||
```

Simple copy and paste the result in the query. You'll have to remove the concatenation from the last line and replace it with the column name.

Comment: thanks it compare the NULL value, any help if i have more than 1000 column to specify, how to achieve.

Comment: You'll have **at most [1000](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032) columns** to specify. I updated the answer with a hint, how you can generate the expression.

Comment: Thanks Marmite... is there any way we can break each line after each transaction.Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd have to add the information how do you identify the two row belonging to the same transaction @Routray

Comment: Hi Marmite, i am using the below query, but output is coming in one line,if we can break in two different line that will be great:select
(case when max(PK_MTF1000) = min(PK_MTF1000) and count(PK_MTF1000) = count(*) or max(PK_MTF1000) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end)as PK_MTF1000,max(PK_MTF1000),min(PK_MTF1000) ,
(case when max(MID) = min(MID) and count(MID) = count(*) or max(MID) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end) as MID,max(MID),min(MID)
from MTF1000 where ORG=' BULGER CAPITAL LLC';

Comment: HI Marmite, we did a blunder here? guess if we have a single row, in that case all will be same, how to achieve if there is a single transaction then it should FAIL instead of compare the same transaction.

Comment: @Routray you show us a table with two rows, so the proposal works. If your setup is different you must update your question accordingly.  Typically you have in such situation a `transaction_id` with the same value in both rows and a `source_name` which is different and identifies the source. Of course with such setup you must `GROUP BY` on `transaction_id`and additionally handle the case of rows missing in one of the sources.

Answer (score 0):

***Issue Resolved:-***

```
select 'ABC' as COLUMN_NAME,
    (case when  to_char(count(ABC)) >1 and to_char (max(ABC)) = to_char(min(ABC)) and  to_char(count(ABC)) = count(*) 
    and to_char(max(ABC)) is  null then 'same' else 'Diff'end)as COMPARISION_VALUE, 
    (case when to_char(count(ABC))=1 or to_char(min(ABC)) is null then 'No Values' else to_char(max(ABC)) end ) as TRANSACTION1, 
    to_char(min(ABC))as TRANSACTION2
    from AAA where MID ='ASD';
```