# How to print the result in different line using SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am executing the below SQL query which result is displaying as in one line but instead of printing it it one line i want to split into two different line and print the value.

SQL Query:

```
select
(case when max(PK_MTF1000) = min(PK_MTF1000) and count(PK_MTF1000) = count(*) or max(PK_MTF1000) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end)as PK_MTF1000,max(PK_MTF1000),min(PK_MTF1000) + CHAR(13) ,
(case when max(MID) = min(MID) and count(MID) = count(*) or max(MID) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end) as MID,max(MID),min(MID)
from MTF1000 where ORG=' BULGER CAPITAL LLC';
```

OUTPUT:

```
same    NULL  NULL diff 1962008204906400    1962008204823K00
```

Expecting Output split into two different line and print the output as below

```
same    NULL  NULL

diff    1962008204906400    1962008204823K00
```

Tried with CHAR(13)

```
select
(case when max(PK_MTF1000) = min(PK_MTF1000) and count(PK_MTF1000) = count(*) or max(PK_MTF1000) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end)as PK_MTF1000,max(PK_MTF1000),min(PK_MTF1000) + CHAR(13) +  --<--,
(case when max(MID) = min(MID) and count(MID) = count(*) or max(MID) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end) as MID,max(MID),min(MID)
from MTF1000 where ORG=' BULGER CAPITAL LLC';
```

Getting error as :

> -ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 2 Column: 189

Is there any way to split into two line?

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want a UNION, so each set of data has its own row.

```
select
    (case when max(PK_MTF1000) = min(PK_MTF1000) and count(PK_MTF1000) = count(*) or max(PK_MTF1000) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end)as PK_MTF1000, 
    max(PK_MTF1000), 
    min(PK_MTF1000)
from MTF1000 where ORG=' BULGER CAPITAL LLC'
union all
select
    (case when max(MID) = min(MID) and count(MID) = count(*) or max(MID) is null then 'same' else 'diff'end) as MID, 
    max(MID), 
    min(MID)
from MTF1000 where ORG=' BULGER CAPITAL LLC';
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, completely agreed with you, here one problem if the data type is different, it won't work. Imagine if i have 1000 column, it will be difficult to add datatype for different column.

Comment: That's true. If you can't easily convert the data types, you might need 2 different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation operator is double pipe `||`, not plus `+`.

Also, try with `CHR(10)` instead of `CHR(13)`.

Which means that line we're talking about might look like

```
MIN (PK_MTF1000) || CHR (10),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's not working out, not printing into different line.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print it like a columns. So you will not get the desired result even after using this CHR function.

You need to contact all the columns into one to get the desired result.

```
-- table structure -- see the "," between column names
SELECT
    '1'
    || CHR(10) as col1,
    '2' as col2
FROM
    DUAL;

output -- not as expected
------
CO C
-- -
1  2


-- Printable structure -- No "," -- single column output 
SELECT
    '1'
    || CHR(10) 
    || '2' as col1
FROM
    DUAL;

output -- As expected
------
COL
---
1
2


-- Your query should be written something like this
SELECT
    PK_MTF1000
    || '  '
    || CASE WHEN MAX1 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE MAX1 END -- CHANGED THIS LINE
    || '  '
    || CASE WHEN MIN1 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE MIN1 END -- CHANGED THIS LINE
    || CHR(10)
    || MID
    || '  '
    || MID1
    || '  '
    || MID2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ( CASE
                WHEN MAX(PK_MTF1000) = MIN(PK_MTF1000)
                     AND COUNT(PK_MTF1000) = COUNT(*)
                     OR MAX(PK_MTF1000) IS NULL THEN 'same'
                ELSE 'diff'
            END ) AS PK_MTF1000,
            MAX(PK_MTF1000) AS MAX1,
            MIN(PK_MTF1000) AS MIN1,
            ( CASE
                WHEN MAX(MID) = MIN(MID)
                     AND COUNT(MID) = COUNT(*)
                     OR MAX(MID) IS NULL THEN 'same'
                ELSE 'diff'
            END ) AS MID,
            MAX(MID) AS MID1,
            MIN(MID) AS MID2
        FROM
            MTF1000
        WHERE
            ORG = ' BULGER CAPITAL LLC'
    );
```

Please adjust the format yourself according to the live data.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejash for the response, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem it's printing as ""same    
diff  1962008204906400  1962008204823K00""

Comment: You need to run it as a script if running from SQL Developer. -- I have updated my answer now. Please check.